# Insert the value of javascript function to database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, function, onclick

i wanna enter a value passed by javascript function to the database. is there a way to do that? thanks.

```
var eng = 0;

var nothome = 0;

var nointerest = 0;
var callback = 0;
var booked = 0;
function myFunction(i,txt, elemid){
var plural;
if (i != 1) plural = "s.";
else plural = ".";
document.getElementById(elemid).innerHTML = txt + i + " time" + plural;
alert(txt + i + " time" + plural);
}

<button onclick="eng += 1; myFunction(eng,'Engaged: ','Engaged');">Engaged</button><span name="Engaged" id="Engaged"></span>

                                    <button onclick="nothome += 1; myFunction(nothome,'Not Home: ','nothome');">Not Home</button><div id="nothome"></div>
                                    <button onclick="nointerest += 1; myFunction(nointerest,'No Interest: ','nointerest');">No Interest</button><div id="nointerest"></div>

                                    <button onclick="callback += 1; myFunction(callback,'Call Back: ','callback');">Call Back</button><div id="callback"></div>

                                    <button onclick="booked += 1; myFunction(booked,'Booked: ','booked');">Booked</button><div id="booked"></div>
```

i wanna insert the value of engaged, booked etcc to the database. is there a way to do that? thanks.

Comment: Short answer: AJAX. Long answer, javascript can't do it directly, but can talk to a PHP service which does the database work, and AJAX is the specific name for this technique.

Comment: i dont knw ajax.. is there a way to do it in PHP??

Comment: @Marc B - Why would this require AJAX? A postback triggered by a JS form submit would work, as well.

Comment: @jared i tried using $_POST[''] but it doesnt seem to work.. i might be doing something wrong.. can you please help??

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be using a `<form>` by all those buttons you have there so let's just use a simple AJAX for your task. You already have a function all you need is another process to throw your stuff to the server and save it.

```
function myFunction(i, txt, elemid)
{
    var plural;
    if (i != 1) plural = "s.";
    else plural = ".";
    document.getElementById(elemid).innerHTML = txt + i + " time" + plural;
    //alert(txt + i + " time" + plural);

    var params = "value=" + txt;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "insert.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            var response = eval( "(" + xmlhttp.responseText + ")" );
            alert(response.Message);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

In `insert.php` you would get your POST data:

```
$Value = $_POST['value'];
// do database connections and inserts here
$Response = array('Success' => true, 'Message' => 'Inserted!');
echo json_encode($Response);
```

I hope you get the idea. There's a bunch of tutorials out there regarding this so give yourself a hand.